# XML to JAVA (JAXB) Error - White space is required between "SYSTEM" and the system identifier

Tags: java, jaxb, websphere, apache-httpclient-4.x

I see a strange behavior while converting XML to JAVA object using JAXB  with the below mentioned snippet (The snippet composed application is deployed to IBM WAS 8.0.0.6). This code works fine for around 20 days in production and then it fails with the below mentioned error after that. But if I restart JVM's then this error is not seen till another 20 days. I suspected memory leak and used profiler but did not find anything alarming. Does this snippet has any issue?

Appreciate your help!!

**Code Snippet:**

```java
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
HttpResponse response = 
HttpClientWrapper.getInstance().execute(httpGet);
String httpGetResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(httpGetResponse);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(
POJO.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

POJO pojo = (
POJO) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(stringReader); // <- Error is thrown at this line
```

**Sample XML:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<usercontext>
 <userdetails>
  <name>TEST CUSTOMER</name>
  <zipCode>48032</zipCode>
  <phone>2343253434</phone>
 </userdetails>
</usercontext>
```

**Stack trace**

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: White space is required between "SYSTEM" and the system identifier. 
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.msg.JAXBMessageProvider.throwUnmarshalExceptionWrapper(JAXBMessageProvider.java:93) at 
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.JAXBDocumentScanner.produceFatalErrorEvent(JAXBDocumentScanner.java:297) at 
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.reportFatalError(DocumentScanner.java:4886) at 
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DTDScanner.reportFatalError(DTDScanner.java:444) at 
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DTDScanner.scanDoctypeDeclCommon(DTDScanner.java:534) 
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DTDScanner.scanDoctypeDecl(DTDScanner.java:481) 
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.JAXBDocumentScanner$JAXBDTDSupport.scanDoctypeDecl(JAXBDocumentScanner.java:58) at 
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.scanProlog(DocumentScanner.java:1757) at 
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.nextEvent(DocumentScanner.java:1324) at 
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.parseDocumentEntity(DocumentScanner.java:1176) at 
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.JAXBDocumentScanner.unmarshal(JAXBDocumentScanner.java:147) at 
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:158) at 
com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:139) at
```

Comment: Can you post some sample XML that produces this error. I have no idea why 20 days would change the behavior, but some other search results for that same message suggest that rearranging the XML headers might prevent the issue.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<usercontext>
<userdetails>
<name>TEST CUSTOMER</name>
<zipCode>48032</zipCode>
<phone>2343253434</phone>
</userdetails>
</usercontext>                                                                                        
                                                                                                                
Please find above the XML response structure. This response will never have DTD and surprised to see the error related to DTD scan after certain days.